# Проблема с Python ftputil

Tags: python, ftp

```
try:
    sav_ftp.chdir("/unicorn-bs.com/www/savorsk/")
    print "We are on FTP"
    sav_ftp.upload("D:\\savorsk\\folder1", "/unicorn-bs.com/www/savorsk/")
except OSError:
    print "Error"
```

Почему-то ошибка вылетает:
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:\savorsk\folder1'

Не могу понять, в чем причина...

Comment: Ну в ошибке же написано, что прав нет у Вас на эту операцию.

Comment: Почему нет? Есть у меня права.

Comment: Видимо, разрешения на upload у Вас все-таки нет

Comment: Разрешение есть, это проблема самого модуля, который не может read only каталоги отправлять на сервер. Однако атрибут read only у меня упорно не снимается. После повторного открытия свойств он стоит снова.

Comment: Это же **IO**Error, нет прав на чтение содержимого 'D:\savorsk\folder1' Попробуйте просто список файлов в каталоге вывести или какой-нибудь файл прочитать оттуда.
____
И да, надо по одному файлу заливать или пользоваться еще какой-нибудь библиотекой http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663787/upload-folders-from-local-system-to-ftp-using-python-script

Answer (score 1):

У Вас нет прав на доступ или на запись в эту папку.
Проверяйте chmod.

И еще. Ты пытаешься загрузить папку в папку?

Я думаю, эта функция работает только с файлами.
Нужно вызывать её для каждого файла
sav_ftp.upload("D:\savorsk\folder1", "/unicorn-bs.com/www/savorsk/")

Comment: Да, папку в папку. Права есть, свое мнение, почему не работает, отписал в ответе Donil. 

Вариант вызывать для каждого файла слишком неудобен для меня. Есть ли еще варианты?

Comment: ты пробовал зайти по ftp каким нибудь ftp клиентом и залить что то в эту папку

попробуй filezilla или total comander